# Как сделать поле ввода на Unity 4.1.2?[C#]

Tags: c#, unity3d, gui

Есть вариант с созданием префаба в котором лежит GUIText со скриптом, но тут свои трудности.

Comment: Разве в unity 4 нет стандартного `Input Field`? Я, конечно, не эксперт, но должен быть.

Comment: Нет, я сам в шоке.

Comment: Думаете, почему тогда вопрос на стеке висит.